# How can I define a new reset?

Tags: sass, compass-sass, css-reset

By including `@import "compass/reset";` in my .scss file, I can have Compass automatically include a simple HTML5 reset.  I'd like to use a different reset, so how can I add my own reset to Compass, or change the default one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way would be to create a partial in the same directory like `_reset.scss` and import that.

The easiest way that would allow you to use it across projects would be to create your own [Compass extension](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/extensions/).

If you create a gem out of it (even just locally), you can just `require` it in your `config.rb`s and then `@import` it into your `.scss` files.